# Merged multiple values in one record value using SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is it possible to merged multiple values in one column using SQL? (the value is being separated via comma)

For example, I have this data:

```
Ids
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

Then I want it to return like this:

```
Ids
1,2,3,4,5,6
```

Comment: `SELECT string_agg(Id::text,',') FROM table_name` **[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/6712/0)**

Comment: @lad2025 thank you very much! just what i need...

Comment: You're welcome. I had to close it because it is obvious duplicate. Good luck with learning Postgresql :)